# Does latest SharePoint 2013 Cumulative update really include all previous Cumulative updates?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, cumulative-update

When a cumulative update is published, it is supposed to contain all the previous cumulative updates.

[KB 4022236](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4022236/) size is 290.0 MB (August 14, 2018)

[KB 4092472](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4092472/) size is 77.7 MB (December 11, 2018) on [download center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57656) and 3.7 MB (???) on windows update

Is the newest cumulative update downloading all the old ones in background?
That would explain why the size is not reflecting the previous ones size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both KB articles you mentioned are the security updates, in the description page, it mentioned it replace the old security updates.

But I would rather compare with SharePoint December CU ([KB4461555](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4461555/december112018cumulativeupdateforsharepointenterpriseserver2013kb44615)) vs August CU ([KB4032247](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032247/august-14-2018-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-enterprise-server-2013)) . If you go throug each cu, you will notice it include that months Security updates as well as previous.

I highly recommend install the SharePoint CU rather security updates only, unless you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've confused regular security update with cumulative updates.

KB 4022236 size and KB 4092472 are not cumulative updates.

[Cumulative updates for SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/sharepoint-updates)